# Disable the collapse action from a Material-UI Stepper component

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a react site using **Material-UI**, specifically, the **Stepper** component.

Is there any way to disable the collapse and expand of each `StepContent` for vertically oriented `Stepper`? I want to keep the styles of the component, but I essentually want all content of the stepper to be visible.

An example of a "collapsing" `Stepper` is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ry36xp2pzn). I simple need to figure out how to disable the collapsing.

I've read the [docs](https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/) back to back and haven't found an obvious way to do this, yet it seems like it should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer Adding `TransitionComponent="None"` to the `StepContent` element does exactly this.

Comment: This solution produces an error because according to the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/step-content/) the `TransitionComponent` prop must be a function and not a string.

Answer (score 8):

Adding `TransitionProps={{in: true}}` works better and does not produce error in the console because `TransitionComponent` should to be object, not a string. 
It basically sets the collapse component to be always open.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `expanded=true` prop to `Step`

`<Step expanded>`

And to active all steps

`<Step active expanded>`